# GET AND UPDATE Quantity in SQL using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm passing where clause and Quantity and Role (to update or less quantity).

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateQuantity]
(
    @WhereClause AS NVARCHAR,
    @Qty AS INT,
    @Role AS INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentQty AS INT;

    SELECT @CurrentQty = Quantity 
    FROM ProductMaster 
    WHERE SKUCode = @WhereClause;

    IF(@Role = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  ProductMaster
        SET     Quantity = (@CurrentQty + @Qty)
        WHERE   SKUCode = @WhereClause;
    END

    IF(@Role = 2)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  ProductMaster
        SET     Quantity = (@CurrentQty - @Qty)
        WHERE   SKUCode = @WhereClause;
    END
END
```

Current status is

```
=====================================================
| ProductId   |  SKUCode     | Quantity  | 
------------------------------------------
| GA10000005  |  GA.42205    |  5        |
```

With query command I'm updating the status like...

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spUpdateQuantity]
        @WhereClause = N'GA.42205',
        @Qty = 3,
        @Role = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

**I got 0 in result** and the status is the same as before

Does anyone have an idea to update stock quantity this way?

Comment: Did you check if the quantity changed in your data?  The 0 may be 0 for success rather than 0 rows updated.

Comment: And what do you expect instead of 0?  What does this return `SELECT * FROM ProductMaster WHERE SKUCode = N'GA.42205';`?

Comment: @Quantumplate Yes I checked but there is no changes

Comment: I want the Quantity to be updated according to role (+/-) and in result is success quantity added or less from Product Master

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. In your example, the `@WhereClause` is **exactly 1 character long** - probably *not* what you wanted. ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `OUTPUT` variable to stored procedure if you want to get back some value rather then using return value which is for purpose of returning status of execution of the proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateQuantity]
(
    @WhereClause AS NVARCHAR(100),
    @Qty AS INT,
    @Role AS INT,
    @NewQty INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentQty AS INT;
    SELECT @CurrentQty = Quantity FROM ProductMaster WHERE SKUCode = @WhereClause;

    IF(@Role = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @NewQty = @CurrentQty + @Qty

        UPDATE  ProductMaster
        SET     Quantity = @NewQty
        WHERE   SKUCode = @WhereClause;
    END
    IF(@Role = 2)
    BEGIN
        SET @NewQty = @CurrentQty - @Qty

        UPDATE  ProductMaster
        SET     Quantity = @NewQty
        WHERE   SKUCode = @WhereClause;
    END
END
```

And use this like:

```
DECLARE @return_value int, @NewQty INT

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spUpdateQuantity]
        @WhereClause = N'GA.42205',
        @Qty = 3,
        @Role = 1,
        @NewQty = @NewQty OUTPUT

SELECT  @NewQty AS 'Return Value'
```

This is regarding 0 as a result. The second part of the question is obvious: change the type to `@WhereClause AS NVARCHAR(100)`. Other way it is considered as `@WhereClause AS NVARCHAR(1)` and your passed value is truncated to `N'G'`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

> nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>   When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Comment: Nothing change in quantity and result return 0

Comment: @SunilAcharya, refresh you browser and see the latest version of the answer!

Comment: Ohh Yes Got the result and mark as answered you Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateQuantity]
(
    @WhereClause AS NVARCHAR,
    @Qty AS INT,
    @Role AS INT
)
AS
BEGIN

        UPDATE  ProductMaster
        SET     Quantity = Quantity + case when @Role = 1 then @Qty else (@Qty*-1) end
        WHERE   SKUCode = @WhereClause;
END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Here - the `@WhereClause` is **exactly 1 character long** .....

Answer (score 0):

Could you remove @role altogether and just call it with a positive or negative quantity?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateQuantity]
(
    @SKUCode AS NVARCHAR,
    @Qty AS INT
)
AS
BEGIN   
        UPDATE  ProductMaster
        SET     Quantity = Quantity + @Qty
        WHERE   SKUCode = @SKUCode;
END
```

Also renamed @WhereClause to @SKUCode as it's easier to understand what it is.

Comment: Nothing change in quantity and result return 0

Comment: Yes I made the changes WhereClause with SKUCode but no result

Comment: It's not matching @SKUCode, try Giorgi Nakeuri's suggestion and change NVARCHAR to NVARCHAR(100).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Here - the `@WhereClause` is **exactly 1 character long** .....